# Read text appearance attributes

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I´m trying to read attributes from a `TextAppearance` style, so I can apply the values to nontrivial components (`TextPaint` for example)
Ideally, I´d like to receive a style id referencing a TextAppearance and read values like text color, font, etc.

I noticed that `R.styleable.TextAppearance` is internal and thus inaccessible, as well as `TextAppearanceAttributes` class.

Is there an alternative to this idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Google Material Components, they have a very useful `TextAppearance` class. It's restricted API, but you can just ignore that:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
val textAppearance = TextAppearance(context, R.style.TextAppearance_MaterialComponents_Body1)
```

All the attributes you need are directly available as members of the `TextAppearance` class.

If that's not an option, then you can always just copy the code they use. Basically it involves obtaining styled attributes using the `R.styleable.TextAppearance` array and its indices from `R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_**` (these are private and part of the [greylist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)):

```java
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(id, R.styleable.TextAppearance);
textSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textSize, 0f);
textStyle = a.getInt(R.styleable.TextAppearance_android_textStyle, Typeface.NORMAL);
// Other attributes are obtained similarly...
```

There's also a few tricks to inflate color resources correctly on all API levels, and getting the font isn't very straightforward. You can check out the code if you want: [`TextAppearance.java`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/0d4515cb460ceaa3b048251aa2e9ece28a170bfd/lib/java/com/google/android/material/resources/TextAppearance.java).